# Get the number of times a unique value appears in a table

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table like so:

```
Email | Number
a     |  0.5
a     |  1
a     |  1.1
b     |  5
b     |  3.7
```

I want to preserve the same table layout, but get the instance number of a unique email based on the ranked order of the Number column:

```
Email | Number | RankOrder
a     |  0.5   |  3
a     |  1     |  2
a     |  1.1   |  1
b     |  7.7   |  1
b     |  6     |  2
```

Comment: what RDBMS is this? MySQL?

Comment: Probably you have your answers, but could you please edit the question so that the output follows logically from the input?

Comment: The output does follow from the input. And this is in teradata

Comment: Output has numbers 7.7 and 6. If this does follow from the input I cannot understand how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a windowed `Row_Number()`:

```
Select  Email, Number,
        Row_Number() Over (Partition By Email Order By Number Desc) As RankOrder
From    LikeSo;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want the `row_number()` function (this is an ANSI standard function available in most databases):

```
select email, number,
        row_number() over (partition by email order by number desc) as rankorder
from t;
```